# How do I set focus to CEdit in child dialog that is inside TabCtrl?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, focus, editbox

I have a dialog box (CDialog) with owner-drawn CTabCtrl in it. Tabs content are child dialogs (one for each tab). There is an CEdit in each tab. When the user clicks a tab, I'm hiding all child dialogs using ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) and showing a selected one.

The problem is that when I have, for example, two tabs, click inside an edit box in the first tab and then switch to second, input focus stays on that (invisible) edit box in the first tab no matter what I do in my code (tried calling all methods that potentially can set focus, nothing changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_YOURCONTROL)->SetFocus();
```

Or the related variable linked with the control:

```
m_YOURCONTROLControl.SetFocus();
```

Comment: Is the control visible before setting the focus? Another option is to set the tab (it has to have explicit ID) itsef first and then the control.